# $e^{2\pi i/k}\mapsto e^{2\pi i m/k}$ automorphism on the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/k})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-fields, ring-isomorphism

I am currently reading a proof in which they mention $e^{2\pi i/k}\mapsto e^{2\pi i m/k}$ as an automorphism on the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/k})$. I know next to nothing about cyclotomic fields and the books that i have been able to find also just make this claim without proof.

My question is how would you prove that this is an automorphism on that field?

Comment: You would need the condition $GCD(m,k) = 1$ to prove this.

Comment: That is not a problem:)

Comment: You need to prove that the cyclotomatic polynomial $\Phi_k$ is irreducible, then it follows immediately that for $\gcd(m,k)=1$ it is an automorphism of $\Bbb{Q}[e^{2i\pi /k}]$.